# Chuck Norris vs. This Question

Tags: visual, rebus, computer-puzzle

`public var c:` [image] `= Infinity;`

`public var w:Array = [`[image]`,`[image]`,`
                      [image]`,`[image] `];`

```
for(i = 0; i < w.length; i++){
    if(chuck(i)){
        x++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
trace(x);

function chuck(i):Boolean{  
    return c > w[i];
}
```

### What does $x$ represent?

Comment: This is a very interesting combinatorial puzzle! +1

Comment: If every Chuck Norris joke had been this clever, the meme wouldn't have died such a painful death.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This looks like

> How much wood would a wood Chuck chuck if a wood Chuck could chuck wood?

because

> Chuck Norris has a wood grain pattern, thus "wood Chuck," and there's an array of wood, and Chuck vs wood.

also, X should be ...

> The amount of wood a wood Chuck would chuck. It is logging for the logging, so to speak. It looks like 4 in this case, but I'm not completely sure since `x` is never instantiated.